# Textview value must change itemView background color with if statement

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, background

Very simple solution probably, but I just can't figure it out. I would like the background color of my itemView of a recyclerView to change according to a value of a textView, which I set in my Arraylist.

```
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewTwoHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvBrand.setText((CharSequence) modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getBrand());
    holder.tvImage.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getImage())));
    holder.tvUnits.setText(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getNumberCases()));
    holder.tvPosisie.setText(String.valueOf(modelTwoArrayList.get(position).getPosisie()));
    if(tvPosisie == 6) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
     else if(tvPosisie == 7) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else if (tvPosisie == 4) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Nothing happens. The app doesn't crash, but the background color stays white. Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change a part of your code to the following:

```
if ("6".equals(holder.tvPosisie.getText().toString())) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
} else if("7".equals(holder.tvPosisie.getText().toString())) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
} else if ("4".equals(holder.tvPosisie.getText().toString())) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
} else { 
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`tvPosisie == 6`

with

`tvPosisie.getText().equals("6");`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Change your ifs:
`if (tvPosisie.getText().toString() == "6")`...

Comment: This line is checking to see if the reference of the String is equal to the String 6. Use .equals() when comparing Strings.

Comment: When you compare the text value of a TextView and a constant String, or even the text values of 2 TextViews the == operator does not check for reference equality. You can test it.